# What is the idiomatic way to slice an array relative to both of its ends?

Tags: arrays, powershell, slice, idioms, language-comparisons

Powershell's array notation has rather bizarre, albeit documented, behavior for slicing the end of arrays.  This section from [the official documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx) sums up the bizarreness rather well:

> Negative numbers count from the end of the array. For example, "-1" 
>   refers to the last element of the array. To display the last three
>   elements of the array, type:
>
> ```
> $a[-3..-1]
> ```
>
> However, be cautious when using this notation.
>
> ```
> $a[0..-2]
> ```
>
> This command does not refer to all the elements of the array, except
>   for  the last one. It refers to the first, last, and second-to-last
>   elements in the array.

The following code confirms the bizarreness:

```
$a = 0,1,2,3
$a[1..-1]
```

Which indeed outputs this bizarre result:

```
1
0
3
```

So, the question is, what *is* the idiomatic way to slice with one index relative the start and another relative the end of the array?

Please tell me it's something better than this ugly mess:

```
$a[1..($a.Count-1)]
```

---

Edit:

Another way to describe what I'm looking for is this: The idiomatic Powershell equivalent of this python expression:

```
a=1,2,3,4
a[1:-1]
```

Which, of course, evaluates to `(2,3)`

Comment: I believe what one considers bizarre or strange may appear completely normal to another. Case in point, I read through your snippets without reading your rationale -- just to see how I naturally interpret the expressions -- and the way Powershell behaves seems to be aligned with what I expected. Just saying -- that opinions will differ. Invariably.

Comment: @amn Your comment prompted me to reread this as well.  Indeed the way PowerShell behaves aligns with what I now expect.  Apparently my opinion differs even with whomever I was five years ago.

Comment: I know how you feel, I think. Powershell parser was throwing curveball after curveball at me, as if to tell me I am never going to understand how exactly Powershell works, but at least I beat it, or so it feels. There are still quirks I am *a bit* unsure about -- array literals (yes, I have read [this piece](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/array-literals-in-powershell/)), to name one -- but the parser seems more or less digested. And yeah, old opinions -- gee, I often cringe at my earlier questions, answers and comments :/ Here is hoping this won't be one of them!

Comment: I agree with Old OP, this is NOT a slicing operator and it's a bizarre result. But unlike old me I know that ".." is a range generator so it does make sense. I'm just disappointed that Powershell doesn't have an array slice operator.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you want to get *n* elements from the end of an array simply fetch the elements from *-n* to *-1*:

```
PS C:\> $a = 0,1,2,3
PS C:\> $n = 2
PS C:\> $a[-$n..-1]
2
3
```

**Edit:** PowerShell doesn't support indexing relative to both beginning *and* end of the array, because of the way `$a[$i..$j]` works. In a Python expression `a[i:j]` you specify `i` and `j` as the first and last index respectively. However, in a PowerShell `..` is the [range operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx), which generates a sequence of numbers. In an expression `$a[$i..$j]` the interpreter first evaluates `$i..$j` to a list of integers, and then the list is used to retrieve the array elements on these indexes:

```
PS C:\> $a = 0,1,2,3
PS C:\> $i = 1; $j = -1
PS C:\> $index = $i..$j
PS C:\> $index
1
0
-1
PS C:\> $a[$index]
1
0
3
```

If you need to emulate Python's behavior, you *must* use a subexpression:

```
PS C:\> $a = 0,1,2,3
PS C:\> $i = 1; $j = -1
PS C:\> $a[$i..($a.Length+$j-1)]
1
2
```

Comment: Hmm...this seems to just be indexing relative the end of the array (ie. same idea as the first example in the documentation `$a[-3..-1]`).  What I'm really looking for is an idiomatic way to index from both beginning and end of an array in once slice. I have edited my question to hopefully make this more clear.

Comment: @alx9r See updated answer. `:` in Python and `..` in PowerShell do fundamentally different things, so AFAICS you're out of luck.

Comment: @matt That composition doesn't work if the array isn't sorted.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for the precise answer.  It's all clear now.  `0..-2` evaluates to `0,-1,-2` which is completely consistent with the documented bizarre slicing behavior.

Comment: If you need from the beginning to some near end index, I think `$a[-$a.Count..-2]` is worth a mention. This also offers an alternative for emulating Python's behavior at the end: `$a[(-$a.Count+$i)..($j-1)]`. I think that's a *tad* more intuitive to look at since it has a simple operation at each end, but that may be a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 27):

Although not as neat as you might want but is cleaner in the way PowerShell works ...

```
@( 1,2,3,4 | Select-Object -Skip 1 )
```

returns ...

```
2
3
4
```

Surrounding the whole expression with @(...) eliminates the unwrapping of 1-element arrays, so that :

@( 1,2 | Select-Object -Skip 1 ) -is [Array]

returns

```
True
```

Comment: Can't use this approach if you're working with typed arrays. Select-Object will return an Object[] so if you work with an interface that requires a specific type it'll fail.
`([int[]] @(1,2,3) | Select-Object -Skip 1).GetType()`

Comment: If the resulting length is 1 item, you get the bare item instead of an array of length 1! Means that subsequent code has to check what happened and can't just say a[0].

Comment: @RiverHeart Select works fine, you just have to cast the result (though it isn't elegant or concise): `([int[]]([int[]] @(1,2,3) | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 1)).GetType()`

Answer (score 6):

Combine `Select-Object -Skip` and `Select-Object -SkipLast` like:

```
$a = 0,1,2,3
$a | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 1
```

Returns:

```
1
2
```

Not as elegant as Python, but at least you don't have to use `Count` or `Length`, meaning this also works if the array isn't stored in a variable.

Answer (score 4):

This could be the most idiomatic way to slice an array with both of its ends:

$array[start..stop] where stop is defined by taking the length of the array minus a value to offset from the end of the array:

```
$a = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
$start = 2
$stop = $a.Length-3
$a[$start..$stop]
```

This will return 
3 4 5 6 7

The start value starts counting with zero, so a start value of '2' gives you the third element of the array.  The stop value is calculated with ($a.Length-3), this will drop the last two values because $a.Length-3 itself is included in the slice.

I have defined $start and $stop for clarity, obviously you can also write it like this:

```
$a = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
$a[2..($a.Length-3)]
```

This will also return 3 4 5 6 7

Answer (score 3):

```powershell
$arr = @(10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

$arr | Select-Object -First 5 | Select-Object -Index (@(0..4) | Where-Object { $_ % 2 -eq 0}) 
$arr | Select-Object -Last 5
$arr | Select-Object -Unique
$arr | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique
$arr | Where-Object {  $_ % 5 -eq 0 } | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique
$arr | Select-Object -First ($arr.Count - 3)
```

Actually code speaks for itself.
I event don't need to explain.

However,

1. Provide the first five elements, but each second of those five. Equal to arr[:5:2] in Python
2. Get the last five elements.
3. Gives unique elements
4. Firstly sort and then provide unique
5. Gives only elements which equal 0 by applying modulo of 5, sort, unique.
6. Provide the first count of elements in that array minus three elements only.

Comment: An explanation would be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for, say, the first three and last three elements in an array, with the results in an array, a little array addition will take care of the need.

```
[array]$A = (([int][char]'A')..([int][char]'Z')) | ForEach-Object {[char]$_}
$B = $A[0..2]+$A[-3..-1]
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Original List"
Write-Host $A -NoNewline -Separator ', '
Write-Host
Write-Host "First three and last three"
Write-Host $B -NoNewline -Separator ', '
```

Yields:

```
Original List
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z
First three and last three
A, B, C, X, Y, Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately piping your array to `Select-Object -Skip $skipStart | Select-Object -SkipLast $skipEnd` is the only foolproof idiomatic way to get the correct items out.

(@wensveen got there first with this strategy, but SO won't let me comment yet, and I think giving an explanation warrants the detail of a full reply.)

##### Calculating ranges doesn't work

Ranging from `$a[3..$a.count-3]` and so on doesn't work if your list is shorter than you expect: supposing `$a` has 4 items, the range you'd end up with is `3..1`, i.e. `@(3, 2, 1)`, three items in reverse order, whereas in the Python example `a[3:-3]` would return zero elements, because the ascending range that starts three from the start and ends three from the end is empty. (In Python, range order is an additional explicit parameter, `a[-1:1:-1]` permits a reverse-ordered result.)

##### Output format

As per usual, if you need to force the output to be an array, you can wrap the pipeline in a `@(...)` array coercion. @RiverHeart mentioned wanting to preserve the input array type e.g. `Int32[]`, but as far as I can tell that doesn't work with ordinary indexing either, I might be missing something.

##### Getting the right items

Another brief mention: the numbers you use are sliiightly different for the skip operation than the range notation. If you're starting at index 1, you're also skipping 1 item from the start in a zero-indexed array, so that one's the same; but skipping 1 at the end is equivalent to index `-2`, or equally `$a.count-2`, for the second-last element.

##### Adding array indexes

Finally, adding range literals together is a nice feature. It doesn't generalise for the reasons above, it won't stop you from accidentally getting the same item twice, say, if your ranges overlap, but it's nice to be able to go `$a[0..2+-3..-1]` at an interactive prompt to get the first two and last three, more succinct than making and combining separate arrays and still quite clear. I guess if you want to thumb your nose at Python, that's one thing it doesn't do quite as simply!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the right way to do it. all other methods require more code.

```
$a[1..($a.Count-1)]
```

Also, if array is converted to string it becomes easy to get data as below:

```
$a = 0,1,2,3
[string]::Concat($a).Substring(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case of shifting a parameter or two:

```
$__, $rest = $a
```

will result in `$rest` being `$a[1..($a.Count-1)]`

Except of course when $a has length 2.