# Getting last X characters from each line PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the last 8 characters of every line of an array in the pipeline,
I thought this would output the last 8 characters but the output seems to be blank

```
foreach($line in $Texfile) 
{
$line[-8..-1]-join ''
}
```

Comment: How are you defining `$Texfile`? (`Get-content xxx`, `Get-Content xxx -raw`, or something else?) And did you have a typo and mean `$Textfile`?

Comment: If you curious *why* `-8..-1` doesn't produce expected result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28461189/4424236

Comment: @beatcracker The post you linked is not relevant. You can use negative indexes on strings and character arrays. For example try `'1234'[-3..-1]` In the SeanBateman's question, `-8..-1` interpolates into `-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1` each of which is a valid index (assuming the line long enough). The question you linked is an issue using both a positive start and a negative end.

Comment: The code you posted should normally do what you want. Please provide sample input and show how you read that input, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BenH Woe unto me! I'll leave my original comment as-is, to be eternally reminded that just glancing over the question is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

There's any number of ways to do this, but I opted to pipe Get-Content to ForEach-Object.

```
Get-Content -Path <Path\to\file.txt> | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Substring($_.Length - 8)
}
```

In your example, you'd use $Line in place of $_ and *not* pipe to ForEach-Object, and instead, use the Foreach language construct as you've done.

```
Foreach ($Line in $TextFile) {
    $Line.Substring($Line.Length - 8)
}
```

Comment: The problem with using the `Substring()` method is that it will throw an error if the string is shorter than 8 characters. The index operater is a safer approach.

Comment: this one threw super-weird errors for me under different conditions. Moved to the other other option.  like was throwing nulls with longer names and such. Worked some times, not others.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach ($Line in $Texfile) {
  $Line.Remove(0, ($Line.Length - 8))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That works fine.  You misspelled $textfile though, with no "t".  Maybe that's why you had no output.

Or (-join on the left side):

```
'1234567890
1234567890
1234567890' | set-content file
$textfile = cat file

foreach($line in $textfile) 
{
  -join $line[-8..-1]
}


34567890
34567890
34567890
```